# How we get user facebook album pictures, This api is not working

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
function photos(){

     FB.api( "/{839506469483059}/photos", function (response) { if (response && !response.error) {
  var photos_name =  document.getElementById("statusq").innerHTML = response.picture;
      }
    }
);
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient error description, we can only guess what the issue could be. check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`FB.api("/839506469483059/photos", ...`

Put a `console.log(response)` in the callback to see any error or data. You will get an array of pictures, so "response.picture" is definitely wrong.

The ID does not seem to be public, i assume it´s the album of a user profile. In that case, you need to authorize that user with the `user_photos` permission first.

Here´s an example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Edit: Since the ID seems to be a user ID, you should add some fields to get more data, and you should not use the ID but "me":

```
FB.api('/me/photos', {fields: 'picture'}, ...
```

Make sure you authorize with `user_photos`, or you will get an empty array.

Comment: When i put console.log(response) it give this error, sdk.js:88 Uncaught ReferenceError: loadAlbums is not defined

Comment: are you sure that is the exact error message? looks weird. how did you get that id anyway?

Comment: this my facebook id

Comment: how did you get it then? by authorization with FB.login? you wrote "get album pictures", but there is no album.

Comment: check out the edited part of my answer.

Comment: function photos() {
        FB.api('/839506469483059/photos', {fields: 'picture'}, function (response) {
//     FB.api( "/{839506469483059}/photos", function (response) { if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
    
  var photos_name =  document.getElementById("statusq").innerHTML = response.picture;
alert(photos_name);
        });
    }               console give the proper result    :-

Comment: console result :  Object {data: Array[0]}
data
:
Array[0]
__proto__
:
Object
__defineGetter__
:
__defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
__defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
__lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
__lookupSetter__()

Comment: please sir , tell me how i print data

Comment: why not use /me/photos? it is pointless to use the id.

Comment: empty array - looks like there just are no photos.

Comment: sir i use this /me/photos, But it give same result .

Comment: then you either have no photos or you forgot to authorize with user_photos. i have added that info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**javascript code :**

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<put your api key here>',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,hometown,last_name,location,middle_name,first_name,gender,picture,birthday', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';

    FB.logout(function(response) {
        // Person is now logged out
        console.log('LOGOUT',response)
        });
    });
  }

  function Login()
    {

        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                testAPI();
            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});


    }
</script>
```

**HTML :**

```
<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->
<img src="http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/LoginWithFacebook.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="Login()"/>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,user_birthday,user_hometown" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
```

Comment: hlo aman,              function photos() {
        
        FB.api('/me?photos', {fields: 'picture'}, function (response) {
//            FB.api('/me?fields=photos', function(response) {
//     FB.api( "/{839506469483059}/photos", function (response) { if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
    
  var photos_name =  document.getElementById("statusq").innerHTML = response.photos;
alert(photos_name);
        });
    }                          i am using this function , i want to get all facebook user album photos ?